# C++ error [1] 41387 illegal hardware instruction

Tags: c++

I am writing a program to take in a user value, return a changed version back. When it builds fine, but when I run it and insert a word I get an error saying "[1]    41387 illegal hardware instruction". I am new to C++ so I'm not sure what to do, let me know if I need to explain more

```
using namespace std;

string isFeminine(string countryName)
{
    if (countryName[countryName.length()] == 'e')
    {
        string country = "la" + countryName;
        cout << country;
        return country;
    }
    else
    {
        string country = "le" + countryName;
        cout << country;
        return country;
    }
}

string masculineExceptions(string countryName)
{
    string masculineExceptions[] = {"belize", "cambodge", "mexique", "mozambique", "zaire", "zimbabwe"};

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (countryName == masculineExceptions[i])
        {
            string country = "le" + masculineExceptions[i];
            cout << country;
            return country;
        }
    }

    isFeminine(countryName);
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter Country Name: ";

    string countryName;
    cin >> countryName;

    masculineExceptions(countryName);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you building with warnings turned on?  You're not returning a value in all branches in `masculineExpressions`.

Comment: Strings in C++, like arrays, start at index 0, so `countryName[countryName.length()]` is out of bounds.

Comment: You need to have a second look at how indices work. Your `masculineExceptions` has 6 elements, but you enumberate from 0 through 4 (which makes 5 in total). In `isFeminine` you access `coutryName[ countryName.length() ]`, which is not the last letter in the string but one beyond it...

Comment: @NateEldredge: Not out of bounds, just always `\0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`countryName.length()` returns the value of how many characters are in a string. If the string was `abc`, the length of the string would be 3. Because C++ arrays start from 0, this would be out of bounds. You can fix this by simply just changing `countryName.length()` to `countryName.length() - 1`.

Comment: `countryName[countryName.length()]` is not out of bounds in C++11 and later, it accesses the string's null terminator. That being said, a better way to access a `std::string`'s last character is to to use its `back()` method.

Comment: Interesting, but thats probably not what he wanted to do.